# Blocking Tcp Request With Netty

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, netty, future

I am new in netty and my english is not native first of all sorry for this situation I will try to explain as much as I can.

I have a application for connect to netty server and send tcp request. We have to use this server for blocking and non-blocking operations for example;

1- Some requests will execute async i will send request to server and i dont wait response. There is no problem in this case

2- Second case is sync. When i send a request with transaction id to server i have to wait response with same transaction id. I couldn't find clear example about blocking netty request. All of them about promise-future and it's implemented like following lines but it is not thread safe. When i use with ~40tps some request will not collect with response messages some messages are escaping. For example requested 2400 message in 1 min 2000 message ok but more or less 400 message escaped. I saw this 400 message returned from server but future's get method not getted it and getted time out.

Netty Client configuration;

```
Bootstrap clientBootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                    .group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 50)
                    .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host.getIp(), host.getPort()))
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
                            socketChannel.config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(2146));
                            ClientHandler clientHandler = new clientHandler(host);
                            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
                        }
                    });

            channelFuture = clientBootstrap.connect().sync(); 
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Channel future listener;

```
channelFuture.addListener((GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture>) future -> {
              channelFuture.channel().pipeline().get(ClientHandler.class).setResponseFuture(responseFuture);
                byte[] byteBuffer = message.getBytes();
                channelFuture.channel().writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(byteBuffer));
            });
```

ResponseFuture is custom future for get server response. InboundHandler like that;

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf in) {
        String input = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        String transactionKey = input.substring(52, 66).trim();
        if(responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey))!=null)
            responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey)).set(input);
        else
            log.info("[{}] Tcp Response map is empty",transactionKey);
        }
```

And finally i am getting future promise like that;

```
Object obj = responseFuture.get(ddaTimeoutParam, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if(obj!=null) {
          response = obj.toString();
          ddaDelta = System.currentTimeMillis()-ddaRequestStartTime;
      }
```

Sometimes some concurrent threads are running when this line `responseFuture.get(Long.valueOf(transactionKey)).set(input)` working before `responseFuture.get` and inputs are mixing each transaction id. How can i resolve this problem? Can i use netty's other good methods for event send when response received.